# Using Jenkins to build a android project fails

Tags: android, mobile, jenkins

I'm trying to make Jenkins successfully build my project, but I'm getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile'.
> Cannot evaluate module matrix : Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Any idea of what the error is?

Comment: is gradle wrapper configured?

Comment: Is the gradlew command working for you locally on command-line? Probably it is the configuration error from gradle

Comment: The graddle is configured, and if I run the project, is all good. It compiles without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Does your project have submodules?

I've seen this error in a case where Jenkins checked out the code, but I had not enabled submodules in the Git plugin.

You just need to click on <kbd>Add</kbd> under "Additional behaviours", choose "Advanced sub-modules behaviours" and check "Recursively update submodules".